# Word merge field in header loses value in print preview

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have an ASP WebForms app where I use a word template that contains merge fields, to replace them with data extracted from the database. The app works great, the word document is exported, but when trying to print the document, one of the merge fields, which exists in the header, loses it's value and restores to the initial merge field name.

Is this something that has to be fixed from the application's code or is this a Word settings issue?

Comment: So you open a Word doc and it looks fine until you Print Preview?

Comment: Yes! I thought I was good when I saw all the data in the document properly positioned and everything, but I received this bug that people can't print or turn it into pdf. I have no clue where to look at. I'm trying to find something with Open XML Productivity tool but no luck so far. If you have any ideea, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem using OpenXML Productivity Tool. It turns out that you can't add a merge field in the header, so what I did was to put it inside of a textbox. I forgot to mention that part in the initial description. Thus, the text element was buried deep in open xml. When I managed to find it and log what was inside, I found out that I inserted the MERGEFIELD <> MERGEFORMAT. Every time I tried to insert the value that I wanted in this <>, it got reset when I hit print preview. So what I did, based on a suggestion from someone who had a similar problem, was to delete this textbox and create a clean one where I only entered "Test". It needs to have a string inside so that open xml created the element Text (instrTxt). 
In C# I did this:

```
foreach (var hPart in firstDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
{
     foreach (var txt in hPart.Header.Descendants<Text>())
     {
         if(txt.Text == "Test")
         {
             txt.Text = "My custom text";
         }
      }
}
```

So for each header part (because I can't tell for sure in which one it is..it could even be in multiple ones), get all descendants of type text. 
I got a few more than I wanted. I also got a few that contained the page number (since I have it in the header as well). So I added an if to check if it's the text element that I wanted. Once I found it, I added the text I wanted.

So long story short, instead of using a merge field in the header, I just used a text. Perhaps it's not the most efficient way of doing this. Maybe the question still remains, (if I could have inserted a merge field in the header and actually made it work without having word reset the value upon print preview? idk), but this worked for me.